# How can I wait for Socket.IO to have a socket connection established before connecting a user to the server?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm running SocketIO-Client-Swift in order to open WebSockets and communicate with a server. However the problem I'm having is that I want to connect to the socket and then connect to the server with an emit.

```
SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.connectToSocket()

SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.connectToServer(self.myUsername)
```

And those point to functions here:

```
func connectToSocket() {
    addHandlers()
    socket.joinNamespace("/chat")
    socket.connect()
}

func addHandlers() {
    self.socket.on("connectUser") { data in
        print("socket connected")
    }
}

func connectToServer(username: String) {
    socket.emit("connectUser", username)
}
```

Even after registering the handle, the emit is being called before the socket is properly connected. The connect works fine after the connect has been established as I can properly send messages and get feedback after my Log shows a connection.

Answer (score 4):

You need to wait for the client to receive the `connect` event.  That will signal that it is now connected and you can safely send initial data on the connection from that event handler.